# Type The value of the local variable text is not use

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

I'm Ervina and i'm new to Java.
My Jdk version: jdk-8u5
My eclipse version: luna 4.4.0
This error occur in my first line of programing and i can't understand it and i confusing:
My Jdk version: jdk-8u5
My eclipse version: luna 4.4.0
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO82T.jpg)

The value of the local variable text is not used    FirstProgram.java   /First program/src  line 6  Java Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error; it's a warning (notice that Eclipse says "0 errors, 1 warning...". It's merely telling you that you have assigned a value to a variable and you haven't used that variable again.

Do something with `text` (like printing it out, for example) and the warning should go away.

Comment: I'm very sorry but i can't understand your mean printing out
How?

Comment: `System.out.println(text);` just add that line. It will print the contents of `text` to the console.